# Arquillian, Tomcat and Jboss Seam 2

Tags: jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to setup Arquillian in my Web project that uses Jboss Seam 2, Hibernate/JPa and others. I updated my pom.xml inserting the following peace of code:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.arquillian/arquillian-bom -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.13.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

...

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.42</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.42</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.42</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-tomcat-embedded-7</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver/shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.arquillian.junit/arquillian-junit-container -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.13.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

So, the second step after add dependencies in my pom.xml was created a Arquillian Test class, see:

```
package com.projectx;

import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.In;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.Archive;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.EmptyAsset;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import com.projectx.MyService;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createTestArchive() {
        JavaArchive jar = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class).addPackages(true, "com.projectx");
        return jar;
    }

    @In
    private MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void validateValue() {
       ReturnBean returnBean = myService.validateNow(null);         
    }

}
```

Finally i tried run my Test class and i noted that "myService" object is null, the Inject Point didn't work, so i got NullPointerException.

My shot is that i'm not inserting everything necessary in JavaArchive with ShrinkWrap. Is there anyway to create my war in arquillian exactly as maven create ?

**Edit 1**:
I added the following dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-seam2</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Beta1</version>
        </dependency>
```

And changed the version this dependencies bellow, because compability with arquillian-seam2:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
```

But when i tried to start the test, i got the following error:

```
GRAVE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: duplicate factory for: org.jboss.seam.web.webSession (duplicate is specified in components.xml)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.Init.checkDuplicateFactoryExpressions(Init.java:227)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.Init.checkDuplicateFactory(Init.java:220)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.Init.addFactoryValueExpression(Init.java:283)
    at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.installComponents(Initialization.java:1152)
    at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.init(Initialization.java:737)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener.contextInitialized(SeamListener.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

**Solution**:
I changed my container from apache-tomcat to jboss-as-5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Seam 2 extension to make the injection through `@In` in the test working - https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-seam2. Just keep in mind that as Seam 2 is no longer under active development the extension itself is not either.

Comment: i putted the arquillian-seam2 extension but i got the error reported in edited post. Can you help me ?

Comment: Sure, but ideally I would need a small reproducer project. Can you prepare something like this and share through GitHub?

Comment: I fixed the error but i got another , i will create another post to this. I posted the solution in this post.

Comment: So maybe you can upvote this answer as it kinda helped you ;)